# Link Firebase user with another provider

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication

I would like to force users that previously authenticated with Facebook to sign up using a new provider. The reason for this is that I would like to remove Facebook as an authentication provider. I would unlink the user once the user has been successfully linked with the new provider.

For example, the user is presented with new authentication options and the user selects to continue with email. I have the following code:

```
func createUserAndSignIn(
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String
) async throws -> String {
    let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)

    // if user is already logged in (in this case with Facebook)
    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        try await user.link(with: credential)
    }

    do {
        let authDataResult = try await Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)
        return authDataResult.user.uid
    } catch {
        // throw error
    }
}
```

The linking of accounts (`user.link(with:)`) fails with the following error:

`Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17014 "This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request., FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_REQUIRES_RECENT_LOGIN}`

Would this be even be the correct approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to re-authenticate the user. Using the current credential

```
if 
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser,
    let currentAccessToken = AccessToken.current 
{
    // Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
    let result = try await user.reauthenticate(
        with: FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: currentAccessToken.tokenString)
    )

    // Then link the user
    try await user.link(with: newCredential)
    // User can be unlinked from Facebook
    try await Auth.auth().currentUser?.unlink(fromProvider: "facebook.com")
}
```

This is needed for several operations such as updating the user's email, password or deleting the user.

Comment: Should this trigger the Facebook login? The line with `user.reauthenticate` works, but the linking gives me a ERROR_PROVIDER_ALREADY_LINKED. Is the `credential` variable in your example a Facebook credential?

Comment: @José no reauthenticate is for the current account, the credential that you pass to the link should be the new credential. The user signs in 2 times one for reauthentication and one for the new credential. It all depends on your flow.

Comment: Ok, it worked now. The `credential` used for the `reauthenticate` is the Facebook credential and the one used to link the accounts is the new email credential. Having the same variable names for both credentials confused me a bit. The accounts are now linked, thanks.

Comment: @José I am glad you figured it out. Can you click on the checkmark and maybe upvote? I changed the names of the variables to make it more readable

Answer (score 0):

The approach you're taking is close. The error you're getting is because some operations in firebase require a recent authentication to have taken place:

> FIRAuthErrorCodeRequiresRecentLogin: Updating a user’s email is a
> security sensitive operation that requires a recent login from the
> user. This error indicates the user has not signed in recently enough.
> To resolve, reauthenticate the user by invoking
> reauthenticateWithCredential:completion: on FIRUser. [[1]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors#updateemailcompletion)

The steps you want to take are:

1. Authenticate the user with an existing auth method.
2. Prompt the user for their email and password
3. Use the email and password to create an `AuthCredential` object.
4. Pass that AuthCredential object to the user's `linkWithCredential` method.

There's a complete walkthrough for this in the Firebase docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-email-address-and-password-credentials-to-a-user-account

But the key point is that you have to authenticate the user with an existing provider before you do this, even if they are technically "logged in".

Note that the steps are slightly different if you want to link the user to another Auth provider other than email (such as Google): https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-federated-auth-provider-credentials-to-a-user-account

After that, if you wish, you can use `unlink` to remove the Facebook authentication.